# Schengen visa rules

Tags: visas, schengen, norway

I have been issued Schengen visa from Norway embassy. I had plans to visit my brother who is living in Norway. Is it compulsory for me to enter Norway first or can I enter any Schengen country on arrival? My visa is C-type and it's Schengen Statene mentioned in it.